# Começar a contagem do length a partir do 1

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou começando a aprender javascript, e gostaria que alguém me ajudasse a resolver o seguinte problema: Fiz um contador de caracteres simples mas ele começa a contagem do 0, será que existe uma forma de começar a contagem do 1?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>Título da página</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
   <input type="text" onkeypress="contador()">
   <p>
     
   </p>
   <script>
    function contador(){
      var c = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
      var result = c[0].value.length
  
      var cont = document.getElementsByTagName("p")
      cont[0].innerText = result
}
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para uma string vazia, length é 0. Quando você chamar a função "contador" e não houver caracter inserido, deve retornar 0, a menos que tenha um caracter não visível no campo, como um espaço. Se houver a necessidade, você pode somar +1 ao length:

```
var result = c[0].value.length + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta colocar + 1 a seguir a `cont[0].innerText = result` logo a função contador ficaria:

```
function contador() {
        var c = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
        var result = c[0].value.length

        var cont = document.getElementsByTagName("p")
        cont[0].innerText = result + 1
    }
```